# delete/remove temp zip file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyzip

i am creating `temp zip` file in rails `tmp` directory as follows:-

```
zipfile_name = Rails.root.join("tmp/abc.zip")
Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  Dir[File.join(data, '**',)].each do |file|
    zipfile.add(file.sub(dir+"/", ''), file)
  end
end
zip_data = File.read(zipfile_name) # sending zip file.
zipfile_name.try(:unlink)`         # try to remove or unlink the zip but not working.
```

temp `zipfile_name` was **abc.zip20140816-8931-1yl3g60** and i want to delete it after sending but it's not found.

Comment: Try `Zip::File.open(zipfile_name.to_s, Zip::File::CREATE)`.. If it works, let me know..I will explain why..

Comment: zipfile_name.to_s is working as same but i am using this block in Dir.mktmpdir so everytime .zip file also have tmp name that i explained above abc.zip20140816-8931-1yl3g60

Answer (score 0):

```
File.delete(zipfile_name)
```

Try file delete command it should work out.

Comment: It's not working. It can't find .zip20140... file name because it have temp name.